# What is right way to delete element from object Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` with function `ng-click` inside:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.education_list">
   <a href="" ng-click="deleteEducation(item)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

I pass object `item` from `ng-repeat` to function `deleteEducation` for deleting element from `data.education_list`.

So looks function:

```
$scope.deleteEducation = function (item){
    $scope.data.education_list.splice($scope.data.education_list.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

So this way works incorrect sometimes. When I have some element in `ng-repeat` and after delete `item` my template HTML is updated and removes row with another item, not that I deleted.

What is right way to delete?

`data.education_list` is array of objects if do `{{data.education_list}}`:

```
[{"name":"Test1","time":"01 Hun 2004 - 12 Sun 2006","Idusereducation":"86","usereducationIdToUser":"702","type":"1"}]
```

**Problem two:**
If I have object of objects instead array with key:

```
{"1" : {obj}, 2 : "obj"}
```

And if I try to delete element from object by key:

delete `OBJ[1];`
I get the same problem.

Comment: what's in the  `data.education_list` , you forget to catch  `item` in `deleteEducation`

Comment: can you provide the data design of `data.education_list`

Comment: provide a demo that replicates this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `$index`, this is a unique identifier that angular adds to track arrays.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.education_list">
   <a href="" ng-click="data.education_list.slice($index,1)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

### If you are filtering a list

you will need to search for the index.  Then do the splice.  It is a little heavier, but required if you are filtering the list.

**JS**

```
this.removeItem = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.data.education_list.indexOf(item);
    if (index != -1) {
        $scope.data.education_list.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
```

**HTML**

```
ng-click="myctrl.removeItem(item)"
```

[Working Example click to delete and .indexOf vs $index comparison](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRnQvZVr4lLRyrM0WAuI?p=preview)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I stumbled upon this before too, when trying to splice an item in an array inside a forEach loop. xD

Comment: If I do `track by $index` your code will be working?

Comment: as soon as you use a filter in ng-repeat this fails. Not sure why you say `indexOf` doesn't match

Comment: If you have duplicates you need to `track by $index`, but it is not required otherwise

Comment: So you do checking `if` it mean your way would be not work

Comment: The `if` is just to make sure you don't try and remove a value if it can't find it. *like if a user would double click*

Comment: What is `this.contacts`? is it `data.education_list`?

Comment: @Muhad You are correct I updated my answer to clarify

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.education_list track by $index">
   <a href="" ng-click="deleteEducation($index)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Then

```
$scope.deleteEducation = function (position){
    $scope.data.education_list.splice(position, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across the similar problem. In my case, I had to resolve as below just in case if it helps someone.

If you are dealing with objects, please note indexOf works for array not for an Object inside that array. You can do something like below to identify the index and handle this case;

```
$scope.removeReport = function(report) {
    var index = $scope.contact.reports.map(function(r) { return r.id;}).indexOf(report.id);
        if (index >= 0) {
          $scope.contact.reports.splice(index, 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, reposting the same answer to multiple questions is not really ideal. Or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a child item from a 2 dimensional array in an object, you need to define the parent item and then the child item to splice

e.g.
**`myObject[this.parentIndex].children.splice(this.childIndex,1);`**

**myObject** is an Object containing an array that includes children

**parentIndex** is the Index of the parent items

**childIndex** is the Index of the child items under the parent.

You can figure out your own way of looping through the parent and child arrays and deciding which child items to remove.